# SignalR disconnect doesn't fire immediately

Tags: c#, .net, angular, signalr, signalr.client

I am trying to handle disconnect error with reconnection so I used the nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds method for reconnection, but in this case, if the connection is lost or there are some problems with the connection, the onclose handler does not work.

I am using "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.2" package in Angular project

I used "withAutomaticReconnect" option, but it doesn't fire immediately. I get a callback after some timeout.

Connection builder:

```
this.hubconnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(url)
  .withAutomaticReconnect({
    nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: () => {
      this._errorState$.next(true);
      return 1000;
    }
  })
  .build();
```

Error handler (which doesn't fire if I use "withAutomaticReconnect"):

```
this.hubConnection.onclose(error => callback(error)
```

Expecting to handle the error immediately when there are some errors related to connection.

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

After test, I found the correct format should be like below.

```
connection.onclose(() => {
    
});
```

In your scenario, code should be

```
this.hubConnection.onclose((error) => {
    console.error(`Something went wrong: ${error}`);
});
```

After testing, if you restart the signalr server, you may not get the error information, which should be normal. I don’t know if you can see more in the production environment. This is the standard usage, you can also refer to the following Link.

[onclose event in signalr client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54009049/7687666)

---

**Suggestion:**

1. The test above I test in signalr javascript client, and I also reproduce the issue, if it not works, please use @microsoft/signalr 7.0.0 version to troubleshoot problems caused by the new version.
2. I also using reconnectDelay property when build the connection.

   ```
   var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/mainHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect({
        nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: () => {
            this._errorState$.next(true);
            return 1000;
        },
        reconnectDelay: 500 // set the reconnect delay to 500ms
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace).build();
   ```